# Hora 0 com sinal negativo

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma planilha excel o qual alterei o sistema de data para 1904 para conseguir exibir horas negativas. O problema é que frequentemente acontece de aparecer valores **-00:00** quando faço subtração de horários.

Pelo que analisei é porque a data está 01/01/1904, mas no campo eu não quero exibir a data, me importa apenas os horários.

Já tentei usar função *SE* para identificar se é menor/igual que zero e não resolve.
Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Como é a fórmula utilizada para calcular isto? Possui um [mcve]?

Comment: como disse, a formula é de subtração (ex. =F4-E4)...
o colega anterior (deve ter excluido o comentario pq nao vejo mais) sugeriu o uso da função TEXTO. Ficou meio trabalhoso já que alem do uso dessa função, eu tb tenho regras (pra pintar a celular quando menor valor) mas funcionou. Obrigado.

exemplo da solução: =SE(TEXTO(F4-E4;"[hh]:mm") = "-00:00"; "00:00"; F4-E4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido, adaptei a função TEXTO (sugerido pelo colega):

=SE(TEXTO(F4-E4;"[hh]:mm") = "-00:00"; "00:00"; F4-E4)